# How can the elements in SVG can't be dragged out of the scope of SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

How can the elements in SVG can't be dragged out of the scope of SVG? The size of `SVG` is fixed, `circle` can be dragged. How do you make the inner circle can't be dragged out of the SVG boundary?

Address: [Demo online](https://jsfiddle.net/zhangyuanliang/nmbw28nd/5/)

It's best to modify it in JSFiddle, thanks!

---

Source Code:

Javascript:

```
var width = 300, height = 300;
var color = d3.scale.category10();
var radius =16;

var data = d3.range(20).map(function() {
    return [ Math.random() * width/2, Math.random() * height/2 ];
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) {return {x : d[0],y : d[1]};})
    .on("dragstart", function(){d3.select(this).attr("r",radius*2);})
    .on("drag", drag)
    .on("dragend",function(){d3.select(this).attr("r",radius);});

var nodes=svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + 100 + "," + 100 + ")";})
    .attr("cx",function(d) { return d[0];})
    .attr("cy",function(d) { return d[1];})
    .attr("r",radius)
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i);})
    .call(drag);

function drag(d) {
    d[0] = d3.event.x;
    d[1] = d3.event.y;
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", d[0]).attr("cy", d[1]);
}
```

CSS:

```
svg { border:1px solid #d4d4d5}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the drag function, simply constrain the max and min values for the circle cx and cy attributes based on the SVG width/height and circle radius:

```
function drag(d) {
    d[0] = Math.max(Math.min(d3.event.x,width-100-32),-100+32);
    d[1] = Math.max(Math.min(d3.event.y,height-100-32),-100+32);
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", d[0]).attr("cy", d[1]);
}
```

[Here's an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heybignick/ndxd9bk2/4/)

The -100 is to account for the translation that has previously been applied.  32 is the radius of the large circle (during drag).